# Blinking cursor/underscore on older computer when booting off Windows Installation USB Key prepared with the Windows Media Creation Tool

Tags: windows, bios, uefi, windows-installation, rufus

In attempting to install Windows 10 on a newly-installed SSD in an HP Pavilion DV9000 laptop, I created a Windows Installation USB Key using Ventoy and the Media Creation Tool. While I'm able to boot into Ventoy, and select the Windows.iso, I'm then faced with a blank screen with a blinking cursor.

What I've tried, without success:

1. Waiting 20 minutes to see if something changes
2. Using a different, similarly-prepared USB Key, in a different USB port
3. Using Balena Etcher to prepare the USB Key
4. Using a Windows ISO with both 32 and 64 bit versions of the OS
5. Using Rufus to prep the USB Key with Partition Scheme: GPT and Target system: UEFI
6. Look for options in the BIOS related to UEFI (there were none)
7. Look for a BIOS upgrade (none officially available from HP since the machine is over 10 years old)
8. Check to see if Q4OS loads (it does)

Answer (score 1):

The USB Key prepped with Rufus needs to have a Partition scheme: `MBR` and a Target system: `BIOS`.

When attempting to boot using Rufus (Partition Scheme: GPT/Target System: UEFI) on this old machine, the following message appears:
[image: Rufus Boot Error GPT]

Following the second bit of advice of recreating the USB Key using Partition scheme: `MBR` and Target system: `BIOS` will make the Windows Installation work.